# How to make faster the loop to find ids

Tags: java, loops, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Have a scenario that was to collect all the div ids and loop them one by one to complete the iteration. I have done the scenario but it takes more time to pass all the ids.

Can you please suggest how to make it faster.

Below is my code snippet.

```
List<WebElement> listoftab = driver.findElements(by.xpath(".//*[contains (@id, 'tabZ')]/div/div[1]"));
Thread.sleep(1000);         
String clas1 = "tablist";
String clas2 = "tabView";
for(int i =1; i<=110;i++){
    boolean present;
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tabZ"+i+"']/div/div[1]"));
        present = true;
        if(clas1.equalsIgnoreCase(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tabZ"+i+"']/div/div[1]")).getAttribute("class"))) {
            tabloop:
            for(int j=1;j<=15;j++) {
                if(clas2.equalsIgnoreCase(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tabZ"+i+"']/div/div[1]/div["+j+"]")).getAttribute("class"))) {
                    String ls = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tabZ"+i+"']/div/div[1]/div["+j+"]")).getAttribute("id");
                    System.out.println(ls);
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='"+ls+"']/div[1]/div[2]/canvas[2]")).click();
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    break tabloop;  
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        present = false;
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u show the html so that we can understand what to do

Comment: The most obvious way to make it faster would be to remove those sleeps. Don't use sleep: use a wait, so you can proceed straight away one some condition is met.

Comment: please fix the indentation, its hard to read...

Comment: can you share html code for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code as you are using driver.findElement() multiple times.Try to avoid finding element instead store them in a variable.

```
    List<WebElement> listoftab = driver.findElements(By
            .xpath(".//*[contains (@id, 'tabZ')]/div/div[1]"));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    String clas1 = "tablist";
    String clas2 = "tabView";
    for (int i = 1; i <= 110; i++) {
        boolean present;
        try {
            WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tabZ" + i
                    + "']/div/div[1]"));
            present = true;
            if (clas1.equalsIgnoreCase(element.getAttribute("class"))) {
                tabloop: for (int j = 1; j <= 15; j++) {
                    WebElement element1=driver.findElement(
                            By.xpath(".//*[@id='tabZ" + i
                                    + "']/div/div[1]/div[" + j + "]"));
                    if (clas2.equalsIgnoreCase(element1
                            .getAttribute("class"))) {
                        String ls = element1.getAttribute("id");
                        System.out.println(ls);
                        driver.findElement(
                                By.xpath(".//*[@id='" + ls
                                        + "']/div[1]/div[2]/canvas[2]"))
                                .click();
                        break tabloop;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            present = false;
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Try to avoid hard wait also.Better go with fluentwait.